# How to modify the background of a Tab Layout tab's text when it is focused?

Tags: android, layout, colors, background, focus

When I tap on a Tab Layout tab, there's the focus flash that occurs for the entire tab, except when it does, you can see a black box around the text of the tab itself. I want to get rid of that black box so that when the tab is tapped, you don't see the black box around the text from the focus flash.

Here's what I mean (print screen mid-focus flash):

[image: Settings text with black box around it]

I want to get rid of this black box around it. I've tried setting tabBackground, background, tabIndicatorColor to transparent, but this black box remains. Any ideas as to how I can remove the black box around the text?

Here's the XML for the TabLayout:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    style="@style/tabStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:tabBackground="@android:color/transparent"
    app:tabMaxWidth="200dp"
    app:tabMinWidth="200dp"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/textColorSelected"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/textColorNormal"
    tools:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabTextStyle">
</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

And then the styles for both the tabs and the text inside of them:

```
    <style name="TabTextStyle">
       <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
       <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
       <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>

<style name="tabStyle">
    <item name="tabGravity">center</item>
    <item name="tabMode">fixed</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">80dp</item>
    <item name="android:layoutDirection">ltr</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/tabIndicator</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">2dp</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/TabTextStyle</item>
    <item name="tabTextColor">@color/textColorNormal</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was here; our "AppTheme" default style was declared and had a black background color set. Since the application's "AppTheme" was setting the background of the app to black overall, any other tabBackground or Background color sets I did were just overlapping the main background color designated by AppTheme. I changed the AppTheme background color to transparent, and then set the tab and background colors in the activity itself to black, and that removed the black box behind the text when a tab is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the tabBackground from the Layout (XML file) like this

app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
or specify with color @color/....

Here is example look of the drawable selector

Example

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    ....
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
    ...
    />
```

Comment: I have tried setting the tabBackground to transparent, as well as removing the tabBackground value entirely, and it still has the black box behind it.

Comment: Could you share your code

Comment: I just edited the original post and added the XML.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    ...>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text_label_1"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text_label_2"
        />

    ...
</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

Changes to tab selection can be observed like so:

```
  tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

    override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
        // Handle tab select
    }

    override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
        // Handle tab reselect
    }

    override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
        // Handle tab unselect
    }
})
```

Implementing tabs theming
Using theme attributes and styles in `res/values/styles.xml` (themes all tabs and affects other components):

```
    <style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
    ...
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/shrine_pink_900</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/shrine_pink_light</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/shrine_pink_900</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceButton">@style/TextAppearance.App.Button</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.App.Button" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/rubik</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/rubik</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Is all of this really necessary in order for me to make it so that black box isn't behind the text?